# A WCF service behind a firewall generates a wrong wsdl URI

Tags: c#, wcf, firewall

I developed a WCF service and i have published it with IIS. All goes well inside the local network but when the service is accessed by an external client from the internet, redirected by a firewall, the service generates a local wsdl uri that cannot be solve by the client.

Something like this:

- *URI needed*: http://**external_url**/service.svc?wsdl
- *URI created*: http://**internal_url**/service.svc?wsdl

I would like to continue using the automatic generation of the wsdl file without indicating an external path. I also have prove manipulating the *ServiceBehavior* attribute into the service class but the problem persists.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure the serverBinding header for your website within IIS.
Here is a step by step for [configuring WCF WSDL to use external domain name](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-wsdl-xsdimport-schemalocations-link-to-local-machine-name-not-domain-name-while-hosted-in-iis.html)

Comment: The linked document gives a 404 for me, but archive.org has [an archived copy of "WCF WSDL & xsd:import schemaLocations link to local machine name not domain name while hosted in IIS"](http://web.archive.org/web/20100526090820/http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-wsdl-xsdimport-schemalocations-link-to-local-machine-name-not-domain-name-while-hosted-in-iis.html).

Comment: In IIS7 it is simpler: in the IIS Manager, set the 'host name' for the binding(s) to the external name of the system.

Comment: what about for self hosted service?